# Mongoose query to sort, skip and limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my mongoose code which does sorting
And pagination. Here when i am removing sorting
or adding other type of sort no result is coming.
And i have 3000 documents in db

```
  res = await Question.find(filters)
  .sort({'_id': "-1"})
  .skip(args.skip ? parseInt(args.skip) : 0)
  .limit(args.limit ? parseInt(args.limit) : 100)
  .exec();
```

Please take a look

Comment: "-1" should be -1 simply. Here's the list of allowed values https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-sort. Also check if directly executing the query on mongo, is returning anything or not

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
sort({'_id': "-1"})
```

With:

```
sort({_id: -1})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.sort()` command accept as Objects or strings as parameters.

On the Object syntax the values allowed are `asc`, `desc`, `ascending`, `descending`, `1`, and `-1`

```
  .sort({_id: -1})
```

string syntax

```
  .sort('-_id').
```

Note: You don't need the `.exec()` part when you are using promises